# How to delete a device parameter for a cgroup?

Tags: cgroups, sysfs

Values of a specific parameter (for example, `blkio.throttle.write_bps_device`) for all devices are stored in a single file. `echo "$MAJOR:$MINOR $LIMIT" > blkio.throttle.write_bps_device` inserts/updates a value to $LIMIT. It does not clear the file, as you might think. So I see no way to **delete** a value. Also this configuration interface seems to violate [the rule "one item per file."](https://lwn.net/Articles/378884/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same problem, and I found that you have to set `$LIMIT` to `0` to remove that limit:

`echo "$MAJOR:$MINOR 0" > blkio.throttle.write_bps_device`

This removes the entry from the cgroup. If you then `cat blkio.throttle.write_bps_device`, you will not see the entry any more.

Comment: Strange nobody mentioned that in manuals, nor Linux, nor Red Hat.